# Show that 29 divides 3a+2b if and only if it divides 11a+17b

Tags: mathematics

Let a and b be integers. Show that 29 divides 3a+2b if and only if it divides 11a+17b.

I am unable to solve this

1. Am I correct in interpreting this as : "If 3a+2b is divisible by 29 then prove that 11a+17b is also divisible by 29." ?
2. What is an intuitive way to solve this ?

P.S : Peter Winkler has released his book, Mathematical puzzles for free. Here is the link to it :
https://math.dartmouth.edu/news-resources/electronic/puzzlebook/index.php

Comment: The phrase, “if and only if” is sometimes abbreviated to “iff”.  A statement of the form, “P iff Q” is equivalent to (if P then Q) AND (if Q then P).  Two references:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if  and  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Iff.html

Answer (score 2):

Let the number be $x$. Then, 29 divides $x$ iff 29 divides $18a+12b=6x$ iff 29 divides $11a+17b=29(a+b)-6x$.